# Plot a function with modulo conditions in matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a function whose output `f(x)` depends on `floor(x)%3`. However, when I tried plotting it using matplotlib, I got this error: 
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I understand that it's because `x` is an array and so `floor(x)%3` doesn't really mean anything. However, is there a way to make python treat `x` like a single number and not an array?

Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

def f(x):
   if np.floor(x / 3) % 3 == 1:
       return -x + 2 + 4 * np.floor(x/3)
   elif np.floor(x / 3) % 3 == 2:
       return x - 2 * np.floor((x + 1) / 3)
   elif np.floor(x / 3) % 3 == 0:
       return x - 2 * np.floor(x / 3)

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

plt.plot(x, f(x), color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem hasn't anything to do with the modulo operator.  The problem is the use of `if` and `elif`.  Instead, you need `np.where` to create conditions for an array expression.  In your case, one `np.where` inside the first `np.where` is needed as you have more than one condition.

Comment: @JohanC could you please explain how I should use `np.where`?

Comment: `def  f(x): return np.where(np.floor(x / 3) % 3 == 1, -x + 2 + 4 * np.floor(x/3), np.where(np.floor(x / 3) % 3 == 2, x - 2 * np.floor((x + 1) / 3), x - 2 * np.floor(x / 3)))`.   Note that the normal plot function will join all the points with straight lines, but that your function has gaps.  You can use `plt.scatter(x, f(x), color='blue')` to better visualize this non-continous function.

Comment: @JohanC do you know why the function is non-continuous? I didn't think it'd be the case

Comment: Well, that's how you defined the function. E.g `f(8)` is `2`, while `f(7.999)` is `3.999`.  Maybe you want `x - 2 * np.floor((x) / 3) - 2` for the case when the modulo is 2?